# Prevent Spotify notification from making sound

Tags: notifications, spotify

I want to keep my Spotify notifications but I don't want them to make a sound each time they appear.

I know there is an option in the Spotify settings for deactivating them altogether, and I don't see an option to control Spotify notifications within the Notifications preference pane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spotify doesn't register its notifications with the system [properly](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1593851) and since its development future [appears spotty](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/03/spotify-linux-no-development), my solution for now is to **turn off sounds in the "Other" notifications option**. This deactivates sounds for all unregistered applications, but such is the way of things.

[image: Notifications]